# information about connected screen

Tags: linux, monitors, resolution

I'm working on an embedded device that has a screen connected on `HDMI-0`. Now, our problem is, that there are two options of different screens with different resolutions and we will need to define the arguments to `xrandr` accordingly. How can I get information about the connected screen? Preferably the supported resolution(s)?

**UPDATE**

I get:

```
# xrandr --verbose
Can't open display
```

(I only have remote shell access)

and There is no `drm/` in `/sys/class`:

```
root@2d04637:/sys/class# ls
13e10000.host1x  ata_port   camchar_class  gpio         i2c-dev    kone      mdio_bus  net             pci_bus       ptp        rtc          scsi_host      tachometer        trusty_ipc   vtconsole
android_usb      backlight  devfreq        graphics     ieee80211  koneplus  mem       nvidia-gpu      phy           pwm        ryos         sound          tegra-firmware    tty          watchdog
arvo             bdi        dma            hidraw       input      konepure  misc      nvidia-pci-gpu  power_supply  pyra       savu         spi_master     tegra-vi-channel  udc
ata_device       block      extcon         hwmon        iommu      kovaplus  mmc_host  nvme            ppp           regulator  scsi_device  stepper_motor  tegra_dc_ext      vc
ata_link         bsg        firmware       i2c-adapter  isku       leds      mtd       padctrl         pps           rfkill     scsi_disk    switch         thermal           video4linux
```

Our system is an embedded box runing an OS based on Ubuntu Xenial.

Comment: Your `find` command is incorrect - you have to tell `find` to follow symlinks: `find -L . -name "edid" 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thanks for that! I updated the  **UPDATE** accordingly!

Comment: It's possible that your kernel has been compiled with `CONFIG_DRM` disabled or that DRM module is not loaded. Do you have `/proc/config.gz` to check it? And the reason that `xrandr`
is failing might be that `DISPLAY` is not set. Is some X server such
as Xorg running at all in the first place? If it's embedded Linux you
don't have to have X/Wayland.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk yes, there is `/proc/config.gz`, I now tried to `export DISPLAY=:0.0` before `xrandr --verbose` but get a load of information which I assume include thge supported resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `xrandr --verbose` should already be able to output information on the connected screens. If you plug in a monitor and run the command, you should get a list of supported resolutions. **As noted by Arkadiusz Drabczyk**, you should make sure to have the `DISPLAY` environment variable set when using `xrandr`.

Alternatively, you could try locating the sub-directory corresponding to your graphics connector in the `/sys` directory tree (it should look something like `/sys/class/drm/cardNumber-HDMI-anotherNumber`) and run `edid-decode` on the `edid` file in that directory, as in

```
edid-decode /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-0/edid
```

Depending on which linux flavor and version you are using, you may have to install that software using your distribution's package manager (on Debian-based systems, the package is called `edid-decode`).

Comment: Thanks AdminBee, please see the update I've added **UPDATE** to the original post